# Rails/ Nokogiri installation errors on Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, homebrew, osx-yosemite

After upgrading my Macbook air to Yosemite, I haven't been able to install rails.  There's been a whole train of errors, and some of them I've been able to resolve.  The current error, which I've been working unsuccessfully for days to resolve, looks like this

```
naomi$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150330-94892-1kd8mkt.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
--use-system-libraries
/Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from extconf.rb:395:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

When I try to install nokogiri, I get

```
naomi$ gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150330-94919-1a0u8fd.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
--use-system-libraries
/Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/naomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from extconf.rb:395:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/naomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/naomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I'm running OSX 10.10.2, and `ruby -v` gives me

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Note: this may seem like a duplicate, but I believe it's not: I've been investigating solutions suggested on SO and elsewhere for days, and the posted solutions haven't resolved the error.  Xcode is installed, with developer tools, so `xcode-select --install` gives me

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Holy moly, this appears to have fixed the issue--thank you so much!!  Rails installed successfully after running that command and installing nokogiri.

Comment: just put my first comment into an answer!

Comment: just be aware that your are mixing RVM and using sudo to install gems.  This is going to lead so some weird behavior down the road.  When using RVM you shouldn't use sudo to install anything.. So before you get too far. I would probably look at removing my gems,, and the rebuilding everything without the use of sudo. so that you don't wind up with odd permissions/ownership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a related issue (the very last post) on [Nokogiri's site](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1231).They solved the problem with:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.‌​platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

Comment: Edited my answer with the related link!

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

For some reason Apple’s Yosemite version of OSX does not have a system accessible installation of **libxml2**.  Nokogiri requires this in order to compile and luckily Xcode has a version of libxml2 bundled with it — we just need to specify it when installing the gem.  It’s important to get Nokogiri installed correctly because as of right now Rails 4.2.1.rc4 automatically attempts to install it and you will feel pain.

**The Fix**

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```